# Use docker run command to initialize a project

Tags: node.js, docker

I am looking for a way to initialize projects using the `docker run` command. I will be using node as an example.

### Attempt

This is the command I tried.

```bash
docker run --rm -it -v "$PWD":/usr/app -w "/usr/app" --name foo_bar node:lts "npm init"
```

This however results in this error.

```js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1050
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module '/npm init'
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1047:15)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:893:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.14.0
```

Not sure why it is complaining about '/npm init' so an explanation of what is really going wrong here is also welcome.

### Expected Result

The `npm init` cli tool would start asking me to set the project name, version, et cetera and the following output would be in my current output directory.

I tried a variant of the command

```bash
docker run --rm -it -v "$PWD":/usr/app -w "/usr/app" --name foo_bar node:lts bash
```

This connects me to the container where I have run `npm init` to create the project which works but I want to do these in one go.

Comment: Can you just install Node and directly run `npm init` without involving Docker?  It seems like this would save some effort and frustration, especially since you'd have to repeat this long-winded `docker run ...` invocation every time you wanted to use Node for anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`docker container run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) has the following syntax

```
$ docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

When you wrap your command along with it's arguments in quotes its considered as a single command i.e. `"npm init"` is considered a command (COMMAND = npm init) instead of it being parsed as COMMAND = npm; ARG = init.

Consider the below example:
[image]

Fix:

```
docker run --rm -it -v "$PWD":/usr/app -w "/usr/app" --name foo_bar node:lts npm init
```

---

Now, why does "npm init" give an error `Error: Cannot find module '/npm init'` but not ***command not found***. It's because of the way `node:lts` image is built. If you look at [node's Dockerfile on github](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/main/19/alpine3.17/Dockerfile) at the bottom there are two lines.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]

CMD [ "node" ]
```

node image's ENTRYPOINT executes "docker-entrpoint.sh" file and it's parameter is "node". On inspecting [`docker-entrypoint.sh`](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/main/19/alpine3.17/docker-entrypoint.sh)

There's a comment

```bash
# Run command with node if the first argument contains a "-" or is not a system command.
```

This is reason why you get Module not found error when you write "npm init" as it's not system command it is run with node. But when its a system command it executes it as is.